# Calculating a rectangle between 2 points and detecting if a position is within

Tags: 3d, geometry

I'm attempting to basically create a road within a game, and am struggling with how I can detect if my existing geometry is in fact on this road.

Basically I have a list of x,y,z coordinates and if I draw a straight line between all of them that's the path I want to follow (assume an arbitrary width).

The problem is I have a list of normals/vertices/indices and don't know how to "detect" what is within the bounds of my road and what isn't.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can basically right a function that says:

IsPointOnRoad(float[3] point)

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?  I'm WAY rusty on my math, sadly, and have been trying to think this through.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be able to give you a usable answer it would help if you describe the other objects. Can we consider them to be points for example? Or are they complex 3d shapes?

Comment: Ahh good point sorry, basically i have vertices that represent triangles (just for the ground, nothing complex like buildings or anything).  The most complex would be stairs, but I really just want to know if a point is considered on the road ya know?

Comment: How did you represent your road, mesh? the parameters of the function you provide only has 3 points, are you sure you use only 3 points for a road?

Answer (score 0):

Found this via google after much searching (my app uses GLM):

http://folk.uio.no/bartloms/teaching/INF3320/2012/code/LineSegment.hpp

Big help!